# update statement not working, also how to wrap two statements in one mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, insert, transactions, insert-update

first of mysql statement is seems fine but will not run:

Statement:

```
$sql = "UPDATE ('bands') SET ('Stock' = 'Stock' - 1) WHERE ('Band_id' = '$Band_id')";
```

also I wish to run this statement and this one together:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (band_id,user_id,user_name,band_name,band_venue) VALUES('$band_id', '$user_id', '$user_name', '$name', '$venue')";
```

I know I need to do it in a transaction but ive google it and do not understand how to do this.

**FULL CODE**

```
    <?php
require 'core/init.php';
$user = new User();

$Band_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$band_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['band']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bandname']);
$venue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bandvenue']);
$user_id = escape($user->data()->id);
$user_name = escape($user->data()->username);



 $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (band_id,user_id,user_name,band_name,band_venue) VALUES('$band_id', '$user_id', '$user_name', '$name', '$venue')";
//$sql = "UPDATE ('bands') SET ('Stock' = 'Stock' - 1) WHERE ('Band_id' = '$Band_id')";

mysql_query ($sql, $linkme)
    or die ("could not add to database");
?>
```

Comment: I am wondering whether `band_id` is a integer not a string.  If so do not wrap the value in quotes.

Comment: Il Update question with more code

Comment: By surrounding your identifiers (fieldnames, tablenames) with single quotes you're making strings out of them.  Don't do that.  In most cases identifiers don't need anything around them, in some particular cases you can use standard double quotes or mysql-specific backticks around the identifiers.

Comment: @fvu thanks for the information il amend the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
'UPDATE `bands` SET `Stock` = (`Stock` - 1) WHERE `Band_id` = ' . $Band_id . ')';
```

If you're using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) (and you probably should be), this is what you need:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$dbh->beginTransaction();
$dbh->exec('UPDATE `bands` SET `Stock` = (`Stock` - 1) WHERE `Band_id` = ' . $Band_id . ')');
$dbh->exec('INSERT INTO `orders` (`band_id`, `user_id`, `user_name`, `band_name`, `band_venue`) VALUES("'.$band_id.'", "'.$user_id.'", "'.$user_name.'", "'.$name.'", "'.$venue.'")');
$dbh->commit();
```

You could improve further by using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: Ok thank you, but if I were to use it like you have written in pdo, how would I call the variables ?

Comment: which variables are you having trouble with?

Comment: dose not matter ive used a trigger in the mysql and got around, thanks for the advice and help though

Comment: No worries. Be careful with triggers, they can make your code very hard to maintain down the line.